# Gstreamer: error when decoding video stream

Tags: gstreamer

Hello I am trying to encode and decode a "live" video using the webcam of and windows pc. The gstreamer version that I am currently using is 1.15.1
For the encoding line I use:

```
 gst-launch-1.0 ksvideosrc ! \
'video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1' ! \
videoconvert ! \
x264enc pass=qual quantizer=20 tune=zerolatency ! \
rtph264pay ! \
filesink location=D:\\cam.ts
```

This make a file on the D drive, but when is try to decode it I get an error.
line used:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=D:\\cam.ts ! \
    rtph264depay ! \
    avdec_h264 ! \
    videoconvert  ! \
    autovideosink sync=false
```

This is the answer Gstreamer gives me

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3064): gst_base_src_loop (): 
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0:
streaming stopped, reason error (-5)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Comment: Try to set the GST_DEBUG environment variable at e.g. 3 to see more output. It could help understanding the reason of the error.

Comment: and ... how do you do that. I am relativity new to Gstreamer and windows powershell